# OS X LaunchAgent WatchPaths does not work, have a PID and no error message

Tags: bash, plist, osx-mountain-lion, launchd

I wrote a small LaunchAgent to watch a folder for changes and trigger a shell script in case of change :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC -//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN
           http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd >
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.myusername.w2</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
    <string>/Users/myusername/Desktop/alert</string>
    </array>
    <key>WatchPaths</key>
    <array>
        <string>/Users/myusername/Personnel</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>WorkingDirectory</key>
    <string>/Users/myusername</string>
    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
    <string>myjob.log</string>
    <key>StandardOutPath</key>
    <string>myjob.log</string>
    <key>Debug</key>
    <true/>
    <key>WaitForDebugger</key>
    <true/>

</dict>
</plist>
```

- The filename is the same as Label
- I used Launchctl to load and start the Agent
- I logged out / logged in my session
- I check with Launchctl list and the Agent has a correct PID and status code is 0
- All my URL are absolutes

Despite all that it is not working as expected : I added a file in the watched folder and the script is not fired.

The log file is created but empty (no error ?)

If somebody can point to the right direction it would be awesome.

Comment: Is `/Users/myusername/Desktop/alert` the script you want to run?

Comment: @chepner yes it is the script

Answer (score 0):

Two things to check:

1. Remove the "WaitForDebugger" key. (At least, removing it allowed me to make a test that worked. Obviously, it has a purpose, but I can't advise on how to attach a debugger to your process.)
2. Make sure `/Users/myusername/Desktop/alert` is executable (`chmod +x /Users/myusername/Desktop/alert`)

Answer (score 0):

Since you have the `RunAtLoad` option set to `true`, your script is launhed right after you login. You're saying that you see a PID in the `launchctl list` output. This means for the launchd that the Agent is already running and no need to run it again.

I would suggest to remove the `RunAtLoad` key or to make the `/Users/myusername/Desktop/alert` script to exit quickly. You will see the `-` sign in the PID column of the `launchctl list` output.